# Space between text in textfield

Tags: html

Please help me to give space between dragged words in text-fields . Is it possible ?? I want to add space between the dragged words so that they would easy to distinguish . Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
    <head>

   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials">
   <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">
   <meta name="author" content="Hege Refsnes">

<style>
     #bod{
         display: inline-block; 

         }
     #drag1{

            margin-left: 0px; 
            background: #D1EEEE;
            border: 2px solid #AAAAAA;
            /*padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px; */

            width: 910px;
            height: 350px;


            }
    #field{
            height:2px;
            width:2px;
            margin:auto;
            padding:70px 20px 20px 1000px;
            }
     #verb {

           width:150px;
           height:70px;
           padding:10px;
            border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
            }
      #noun {
             width:150px;
             height:70px;
            padding:10px;
            border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
            }
 #adjective {
              width:150px;
             height:70px;
              padding:10px;
             border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
            }
</style>
<script>
       var nouns = ['I','am'];
       var verbs = ['computer'];
       var adjectives=['student']
 function allowDrop(ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();
                        }                            

 function drag(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
                   }

 function drop(ev) {
       ev.preventDefault();
       var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
      if(ev.target.id =='verb' && verbs.indexOf(data) != -1){
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
                   }

        else if(ev.target.id =='noun' && nouns.indexOf(data) != -1){
       ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
                                                                   }
    else if(ev.target.id =='adjective' && adjectives.indexOf(data) != -1){
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
         }
    else{
    alert('Not Found');
         } 

 }
```

```
 <div id="field">

     <div id="verb" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    </div>
     <br>
     <div id="noun" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
      <br>
    <div id="adjective" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    </div>
     <br>
    <div id="drag1"> <span id="I" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">            
        <b>I</b></span> <span id="am" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"> 
        <b>am</b></span> <span id="computer" draggable="true" 
         ondragstart="drag(event)"><b>computer</b></span> <span id="student" 
         draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><b>student</b></span><br/>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Apply that property to the fields you need in CSS, i hope it's what you were after :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS property `word-spacing` in order to space the words.

For instance `word-spacing:20px;`

Comment: No Alex ! you are absolutely rite but i want to give space in text box in which we drop the text from field .. For example if i drag the word "I" from the field and drop it into box and then pick the word "am" and again drop it into box there is no space between these words .I want to add space between that words. Please help me Alex and otinanai :(

Comment: I have just tried, if you apply to each box the CSS property word-spacing:20px; for instance each word will be spaced properly.

Comment: Alex, Can you please apply this on my code ? Please !

Answer (score 0):

Since you have each word wrapped in `<b>` tags you can add padding to each word, like below:

```
#drag1 b  {padding-right: 15px}
```

If you don't have any html wrapping the word, I'd go for Alex's answer above.